# Global variable changing value over another class (C#)

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am making a program which at the start of it has a menu button and when pressed sets a global bool variable to true. This variable is used in another forum but it changes itself to false even though it is set to true when the button is pressed

[In the first forum, the global variable is true (i'm running it in debug mode).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN9jx.png)

[In the second forum, the global variable has become false for an unknown reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xebqH.png)

This is the code for when the button is pressed on forum1 (confirmation is forum2)

```
private void GButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Green = true;
        this.Hide();
        Confirmation confirmation = new Confirmation();
        confirmation.Show();
    }
```

This is the code for when the if statement is ran using the global variable in the other forum (menu is forum1)

```
 public Confirmation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        if(menu.Green == true)
        {
            //Set properties for green confirmation box
        }
```

Global bool variable:

```
public bool Green { get; set; }
```

How can I fix this? Any help is **much** appreciated.

Comment: It is because you are newing up the Menu everytime you new up Confirmation class. And bool is by default set to false.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: That's **not** a "global" variable though. It's a public field of Form1 (Menu). And you seem to check that field on a different instance from the instance that has the field set to true. Find yourself a basic beginner's tutorial on GUI App Design (WinForms that is, I guess). If you are ready to take a challenge, I'd recommend to start with WPF right away since WinForms  - while still having it's place and many legacy systems using it - is somewhat outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is:

```
public partial class Menu : Form
{
    public Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Confirmation confirmationForm;
    private void btnRed_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (confirmationForm == null)
        {
            confirmationForm = new Confirmation();

            // if you need for the current Menu form to be hidden, 
            // you would need Confirmation form to be aware of it. That way
            // you can make Menu form visible when Confirmation form is
            // closed. You would need to write code in Form_Closed event.
            confirmationForm.Menu = this;

            // since you mentioned background color would be changed, 
            // if thats the only thing, you could just set that property.
            confirmationForm.BackColor = Color.Red;

            // or if you have other bunch of properties that needs 
            // to be set or logic that needs to be run, 
            // you could create a method in Confirmation
            confirmationForm.SetProperties("red");
        }

        // you may want to use ShowDialog(), so that you 
        // wont have multiple instances of confirmation being created.
        confirmationForm.Show();

        // so that it appears in the front.
        confirmationForm.BringToFront();

        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

In your Confirmation form, you would need to:

```
public partial class Confirmation : Form
{
    public Form Menu {get; set;}
    public Confirmation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void SetProperties(string color)
    {
       // do your logic here 
    }

    private void Confirmation_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Menu != null)
        {
            Menu.Show();
            Menu.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

If I understood you correctly, this should help, else let me know in the comment. I will be happy to help you understand this.

Comment: That doesn't work for some reason. When I try to run it it opens Confirmation.Designer.cs and highlights the code `this.ResumeLayout(false);`

Comment: I may know what the problem is. What are you trying to achieve? is it when a button is clicked in a Confirmation form, you want to set Green property in Menu form and bring that to display? In the current code, when button is clicked in Confirmation form, you are setting Green property in Confirmation form and then creating another new Confirmation form, which in turn creates Menu form as well. Can you please elaborate what should happen when the button is clicked in Confirmation form?

Comment: 1. The program starts and 2 buttons appear (the other one has the exact same code but with another global variable called red). 2. You press the green or red button and it sends you to the confirmation forum. 3. Depending on whether the green or red button was pressed, it would change the background colour to green or red (I haven't coded that yet). And that is determined with those green and red bool variables. But both variables are always false when I press them.

Comment: So, Menu Form is displayed on the start up and it has two buttons, correct?

Comment: Yes, it has 2 buttons at the start called green and red.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted way of passing information between forms, is to set and get properties before and after the form is shown.

For example, if the confirmation status is stored as a checkbox of a menu item

[image: scr1]

the do the following in order to show the dialog box that sets or clears this checkmark.

```
// Set client confirmation box based on current check on menu item
client.Confirmation = confirmationToolStripMenuItem.Checked;
if (client.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Set check on menu item based on results of confirmation dialog box
    confirmationToolStripMenuItem.Checked = client.Confirmation;
}
```

[image: IAgree]